# jps not working

Tags: linux, redhat, java

I have installed java-1.6.0-openjdk-devel.

```
$java -version

java version "1.6.0_24"

OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.3) (rhel-1.48.1.11.3.el6_2-x86_64)

OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode)
```

when typing jps into command prompt

```
$jps

-bash: jps: command not found
```

I do not believe it is an openjdk error because I have used it around 6 months back on the same system and it worked fine. Also, it works fine on my laptop.

Comment: Did you set JAVA_HOME? And where you did it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You just have to put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` in your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: JPS isn't located in that directory--or anywhere--in the openjdk I just installed.

Answer (score 20):

That is common issue. The reason of this problem is that open jdk package just contains jre in CentOs. Therefore, jps ise not preinstalled. In order to solve this problem and develop java applications, open jdk devel packages must be installed.

Firstly, list developer packages and install suitable one with the commands shown belows. Pick the most relevant version from the list in `1` to use with `2`.

1. `yum list java*devel*`
2. `sudo yum install java-<version>-openjdk-devel.x86_64`

Answer (score 10):

jps is not part of the openjdk. you have to install it by using the command

for java 7 - `sudo yum install java-1.7.0-openjdk-devel`

for java 8 - `sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`

Answer (score 9):

Add JAVA_HOME to PATH variable in *bashrc* file if you are using linux based OS.

```
vim ~/.bashrc
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk1.8.0_72/
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 4):

check the installation directory of java i.e $JAVA_HOME

then make a sym link i.e

ln -s $JAVA_HOME/bin/jps /usr/bin/jps

Answer (score 4):

When I try jps I got

> jps: command not found...

Because I did not install jps

and I solved by installing jdk.

```
yum install jdk
```

Answer (score 2):

This command also worked me:

```
alias jps='<your JDK path>/bin/jps'
```

Answer (score 2):

This command worked for me...!
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless

Answer (score 1):

firstly, please make sure jps is installed somewhere. it should be run command `sudo update-alternatives --config jps --auto` to link the jps to `/usr/bin/jps` Or just appending `$JAVA_HOME/bin` to your `$PATH` like the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this command:
export PATH=$PATH:/home/dav/jdk1.7.0_45/bin

its relative path of your java. In this case my java is situated inside /home/dav/ dir.
then run jps
it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add a little more details to this:
"You just have to put `$JAVA_HOME/bin` in your $PATH variable." **@Spudley's** answer.

Note that the way to add that is to use `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to $PATH.

Answer (score -1):

After a two hours. In my case I used this comand in Rhel 7.X

```
sudo yum install java-1.8.0-openjdk -y
```

But jps not installed, It's not appear in /usr/bin/jps, then installed this package and works **jps** command.

```
sudo yum -y install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel
```