# Can't increase heap size

Tags: android-studio, heap-memory

I keep on trying to increase the heap size inside of android studio, but the memory remains the same, anyone know why? Thanks in advance !

[Look at how the heap memory is stuck on 494M](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E9C4L.png)

Comment: What Android studio do you have? how much RAM do you have, how big heap size are you trying to set up?

Comment: Maybe Android Studio doesn't need it. Did it ever max out?

Comment: We can't know what you might have done wrong since you haven't shown us exactly what you did.

Comment: Why do you want to increase heap size ? Did you experience OutOfMemory or something related ?

Comment: @isaaaaame The latest version, I have 16 gb ram, the heap is stuck at 494 i wanna give it at least 2 gb

Comment: @devgianlu yes it did several times while i was working

Comment: @Benoit it keeps on reminding me that its running on low memory and crashes sometimes

Comment: @Michael i kind of tried everything :/

Comment: @RabihKadi really important question: have you saved it after editing the settings?

Comment: @isaaaaame yes i did, turns out i had to change the path also, thanks all anyways !

Answer (score 1):

Click on `Help -> Edit Custom VM Options...`. If you don't have any VM options created, it'll prompt you to create one, accept it. Add / modify `-Xmx` with amount and type of data you want, like `-Xmx8g` for 8gb of heap. You should restart Android Studio afterwards so it'll take effect.

**Edit:** For more information about studio options, take a look at [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html).

**Edit 2:** If you have a problem with `jps`, make sure you added up `$PATH` for java home. See more details [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286669/jps-not-working).

Comment: That's quite weird. Just to test it out, can you save your VM options to elsewhere then clear out everything except `-XmX` option, and restart ?

Comment: Can you try to execute `jps -lvm` in Android Studio console after changing ? Take a look at here so you'll see what to expect after executing it, to confirm your heap changes: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html

Comment: that's the weirdest part, that jps -lvm is unrecognizable on the console !

Comment: May you check if you have set `$PATH` for Java home ? Take a look at here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286669/jps-not-working

Comment: I'm glad it helped, I'll update the answer accordingly. If you mark it as an accepted answer, it may help others who end up here. Cheers !